# Can i override fields name in serilog?

Tags: .net, logging, serilog, ilogger

In a external nuget i found the line

```
  _logger.LogError(ex, "Workflow {0} raised error on step {1} Message: {2}", workflow.Id, pointer.StepId, ex.Message);
```

Fields like 1 2 3 cause problems in my logging system. Can I somehow redefine or rename these fields without changing the sources of the external library. I use serilog with microsoft.extension.logging